# How to fix a connection to https NSIDC/NASA website?

Tags: python-2.7, download, html-parsing, urllib2

I have been working in a python code to search and download SMAP satellite data from NSIDC https website. My code was working until last week when start a bug:

> urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

Any help?

The code Is a adaptation from a NSIDC website proposed to do exactly what I need. The example below:

```
"""This script, NSIDC_parse_HTML_BatchDL.py, defines an HTML parser to scrape data files from an earthdata HTTPS URL and bulk downloads all files to your working directory.

This code was adapted from https://wiki.earthdata.nasa.gov/display/EL/How+To+Access+Data+With+Python
Last edited Jan 26, 2017 G. Deemer""" 

import urllib2
import os
from cookielib import CookieJar
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

# Define a custom HTML parser to scrape the contents of the HTML data table
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.inLink = False
        self.dataList = []
        self.directory = '/'
        self.indexcol = ';'
        self.Counter = 0

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
       self.inLink = False
       if tag == 'table':
           self.Counter += 1
        if tag == 'a':
            for name, value in attrs:
                if name == 'href':
                    if self.directory in value or self.indexcol in value:
                        break
                    else:
                        self.inLink = True
                        self.lasttag = tag

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
            if tag == 'table':
                self.Counter +=1

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self.Counter == 1:
            if self.lasttag == 'a' and self.inLink and data.strip():
                self.dataList.append(data)

parser = MyHTMLParser() 

# Define function for batch downloading
def BatchJob(Files, cookie_jar):
    for dat in Files:
        print "downloading: ", dat
        JobRequest = urllib2.Request(url+dat)
        JobRequest.add_header('cookie', cookie_jar) # Pass the saved cookie into additional HTTP request
        JobRedirect_url = urllib2.urlopen(JobRequest).geturl() + '&app_type=401'

        # Request the resource at the modified redirect url
        Request = urllib2.Request(JobRedirect_url)
        Response = urllib2.urlopen(Request)
        f = open( dat, 'wb')
        f.write(Response.read())
        f.close()
        Response.close()
    print "Files downloaded to: ", os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
#===========================================================================
# The following code block is used for HTTPS authentication
#===========================================================================

# The user credentials that will be used to authenticate access to the data
username = "user"
password = "password"

# The FULL url of the directory which contains the files you would like to bulk download

url = "https://n5eil01u.ecs.nsidc.org/SMAP/SPL4SMGP.003/2017.10.14/" # Example URL
# Create a password manager to deal with the 401 reponse that is returned from
# Earthdata Login

password_manager = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
password_manager.add_password(None, "https://urs.earthdata.nasa.gov", username, password)

# Create a cookie jar for storing cookies. This is used to store and return
# the session cookie given to use by the data server (otherwise it will just
# keep sending us back to Earthdata Login to authenticate).  Ideally, we
# should use a file based cookie jar to preserve cookies between runs. This
# will make it much more efficient.

cookie_jar = CookieJar()

# Install all the handlers.
opener = urllib2.build_opener(
    urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_manager),
    #urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=1),    # Uncomment these two lines to see
    #urllib2.HTTPSHandler(debuglevel=1),   # details of the requests/responses
    urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookie_jar))
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

# Create and submit the requests. There are a wide range of exceptions that
# can be thrown here, including HTTPError and URLError. These should be
# caught and handled.

#===========================================================================
# Open a requeset to grab filenames within a directory. Print optional
#===========================================================================

DirRequest = urllib2.Request(url)
DirResponse = urllib2.urlopen(DirRequest)

# Get the redirect url and append 'app_type=401'
# to do basic http auth
DirRedirect_url = DirResponse.geturl()
DirRedirect_url += '&app_type=401'

# Request the resource at the modified redirect url
DirRequest = urllib2.Request(DirRedirect_url)
DirResponse = urllib2.urlopen(DirRequest)

DirBody = DirResponse.read(DirResponse)

# Uses the HTML parser defined above to pring the content of the directory containing data
parser.feed(DirBody)
Files = parser.dataList

# Display the contents of the python list declared in the HTMLParser class
# print Files #Uncomment to print a list of the files

#=========================================================================
# Call the function to download all files in url
#=========================================================================

BatchJob(Files, cookie_jar) # Comment out to prevent downloading to your working directory
```

Comment: Why don't you use `url` for your requests? `DirRedirect_url` results in 404 response.

Comment: @t.m.adam because the code uses the url base to find the files inside of each folder at website. Because this, there is this extructure, of check at website, get the available files and dowload the data.

Answer (score 0):

I could fix the bug using a directly load of the website and selecting the images to download. As the code above.

```
"""This script, NSIDC_parse_HTML_BatchDL.py, defines an HTML parser to scrape data files from an earthdata HTTPS URL and bulk downloads all files to your working directory.

This code was adapted from https://wiki.earthdata.nasa.gov/display/EL/How+To+Access+Data+With+Python Last edited Jan 26, 2017 G. Deemer""" 

import urllib2
import os
from cookielib import CookieJar


# Define function for batch downloading
def BatchJob(Files, cookie_jar):
   for dat in Files:
      print "downloading: ", dat
      JobRequest = urllib2.Request(url+dat)
      JobRequest.add_header('cookie', cookie_jar) # Pass the saved cookie into additional HTTP request
     JobRedirect_url = urllib2.urlopen(JobRequest).geturl() + '&app_type=401'

     # Request the resource at the modified redirect url
     Request = urllib2.Request(JobRedirect_url)
     Response = urllib2.urlopen(Request)
     f = open( dat, 'wb')
     f.write(Response.read())
     f.close()
     Response.close()
 print "Files downloaded to: ", os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
 #==========================================================================
 # The following code block is used for HTTPS authentication
 #==========================================================================

 # The user credentials that will be used to authenticate access to the data
 username = "user"
 password = "password"

 # The FULL url of the directory which contains the files you would like to bulk download

url = "https://n5eil01u.ecs.nsidc.org/SMAP/SPL4SMGP.003/2017.10.14/" # Example URL
# Create a password manager to deal with the 401 reponse that is returned from # Earthdata Login

password_manager = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
password_manager.add_password(None, 
                              "https://urs.earthdata.nasa.gov", 
                              username, password)

# Create a cookie jar for storing cookies. This is used to store and return
# the session cookie given to use by the data server (otherwise it will just
# keep sending us back to Earthdata Login to authenticate).  Ideally, we
# should use a file based cookie jar to preserve cookies between runs. This
# will make it much more efficient.

cookie_jar = CookieJar()

# Install all the handlers.
opener = urllib2.build_opener(
    urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_manager),
    #urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=1),    # Uncomment these two lines to see
    #urllib2.HTTPSHandler(debuglevel=1),   # details of the requests/responses
    urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookie_jar))
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

# Create and submit the requests. There are a wide range of exceptions that
# can be thrown here, including HTTPError and URLError. These should be
# caught and handled.

#===========================================================================
# Open a requeset to grab filenames within a directory. Print optional
#===========================================================================

DirResponse = urllib2.urlopen(url)
htmlPage = DirResponse.read()

listFiles = [x.split(">")[0].replace('"', "")
                     for x in htmlPage.split("><a href=") if x.split(">")[0].endswith('.h5"') == True]

# Display the contents of the python list declared in the HTMLParser class
# print Files #Uncomment to print a list of the files

#=========================================================================
# Call the function to download all files in url
#=========================================================================

BatchJob(Files, cookie_jar) # Comment out to prevent downloading to your working directory
```